# Ubuntu (18.04) system shortcut conflict with programs

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

How i can resolve conflict with programs shortcuts with system shortcuts?

For example:
I press `Alt+Shift+F` to reformat code in IDE.
But system recognize it as `change language` shortcut `Alt+Shift`.

I **don't** want to change system or IDE shortcuts!

Disable global shortcuts for IDE window is nasty option.

Comment: It's not possible until you change the shortcuts either of IDE or System. As well said - *Change is hard at first, messy in the middle, but gorgeous at the end*.

Comment: Why it will not work like in Windows?

Comment: Don't use KDE, but is it KDE or X doing it? Found a post related to enabling the behavior you describe... editing `xorg.conf` may be able to disable it for you? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=264861

Comment: @ivanivan looks like its not a KDE problem, reproduced on Ubuntu too. I'll try edit `xorg`, thx.